# In XAML, how can I keep an ellipse being a circle?

Tags: wpf, triggers, properties, ellipse

I'm getting XAML-blind I'm afraid. I'm developing a MS Surface application and I have an ellipse inside a ScatterViewItem (a container an end user can resize). I would like to keep the ellipse a circle (width == height) and keep it as big as possible (the lowest value of width/height of the SVI should be taken for both width/height properties of the ellipse).

A XAML only solution (using property triggers or similar) is prefered.

Your help is much appreciated as always.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Would a simple `Viewbox` do the trick? E.g.

```
<Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Canvas Width="100" Height="100">
        <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" />
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

The `Viewbox` will scale its contents to fill the area of the `Viewbox`, and by default does the scaling proportionally. The specified horizontal and vertical alignments keep the `Ellipse` centered when it cannot be stretched to the full size (because of the proportional scaling).

Comment: Briljant!  Briljant (I need 15 characters at least to tell you so)

Answer (score 37):

I stumbled over this question a few minutes ago and found a much better solution than @Paul Betts (I'd comment on his answer if I could, but I can't)

You can simply use `<Ellipse Stretch="Uniform" />` to get a circle.

Source: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/160615.aspx

Comment: This is the best solution by far.

Comment: In order to get this to work with WPF, I had to make this `UniformToFill`.

Comment: @Mitch only if the parent that contains the ellipse doesn't provide a height/width for the ellipse and you didn't specify a height or width on the ellipse. Good point though, I didn't know that `UniformToFill` existed.

Answer (score 6):

```
<Ellipse x:Name="anEllipse" Width={Binding Path=ActualHeight ElementName=anEllipse} />
```

You could probably get away with not naming this if you did a relative binding as well.

Comment: What if the height of the bounding box is greater than the width? In that case I want the Height=ActualWidth.

Comment: In this case, you need to write code to do this - i.e. you want to do greedy sizing that maintains the aspect ratio (kind of like how a movie player does it, that switches which side it bases its sizes on based on which axis is bigger)

Comment: That's what I thought. Too bad, but no problem. Thanks